# Finding Minimum, Maximum, Evens, Odds, and Average. Java

Tags: java, average

As the title stated, I am trying to find the maximum and minimum values, the amount of evens and odds numbers, and the average of all inputted numbers.

The problem. As I run my code, my odds and evens counter seem to read their opposite, odd would read an even input and even would read an odd input. As for my average, I have no clue what is wrong with it, all I know is that it would only find the average of a proper fraction.

Example of my output will be pasted at the end.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework7APrinter
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    { 
        System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integers. Any non-integer to quit");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int oddsCounter = 0;
        int evensCounter = 0;
        int getInt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double average = 0;
        boolean notnull = true;

        while(scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            if(true)
            {
                if (getInt%2==1)
                {
                    evensCounter++;
                    System.out.println("even: " + evensCounter);
                }
                else
                {
                    oddsCounter++;
                    System.out.println("odd: " + oddsCounter);
                }

                getInt = scan.nextInt();

                if(getInt < min)
                {
                    min = getInt;
                }
                else if(getInt > max)
                {
                    max = getInt;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                notnull = false;
            }

            sum += getInt;
            System.out.println("sum " +sum);
            count++;
            System.out.println("count " +count);
            average = sum/(count);
            System.out.println("average " +average);
        }

        System.out.println("smallest: " + min);
        System.out.println("largest: " + max);
        System.out.println("even: " + oddsCounter);
        System.out.println("odd: " + evensCounter);
        System.out.println("average: " + average);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Enter a sequence of integers. Any non-integer to quit
1 //first input
odd: 1
sum 1
count 1
average 1.0
2 //second input
even: 1
sum 3
count 2
average 1.0
3 //third input
odd: 2
sum 6
count 3
average 2.0
4 //fourth input
even: 2
sum 10
count 4
average 2.0
q //quit the scan
smallest: 1
largest: 4
even: 2
odd: 2
average: 2.0 //average of 1, 2, 3, 4 = sum/n = 10/4 = 2.5 not 2.0
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you need to cast your sum as a `double` or `float` before dividing, in order to get a floating point result.

Comment: i guess it should be if (getInt%2==0)

Comment: this is dead code and it will never go to else
            {
                notnull = false;
            }
since your if condition is if(true), it will always be true

Comment: `"even: " + oddsCounter` - this doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

`(getInt%2==1)` is actually a check for odd number, it should be `getInt%2==0` for even check

Answer (score 0):

Few things-

1. Move getInt = scan.nextInt(); immediately after if(true) condition
2. For average make it - average = (double) sum / (count);
3. For even/odd issue make this change - if (getInt % 2 == 0)

So here's YOUR code with some clean up-

```
    System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integers. Any non-integer to quit");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int oddsCounter = 0;
    int evensCounter = 0;
    int getInt;
    double average = 0;

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {

        getInt = scan.nextInt();
        if (getInt % 2 == 0) {
            evensCounter++;
            System.out.println("even: " + evensCounter);
        } else {
            oddsCounter++;
            System.out.println("odd: " + oddsCounter);
        }

        if (getInt < min) {
            min = getInt;
        } else if (getInt > max) {
            max = getInt;
        }

        sum += getInt;
        System.out.println("sum " + sum);
        count++;
        System.out.println("count " + count);
        average = (double) sum / (count);
        System.out.println("average " + average);
    }

    System.out.println("smallest: " + min);
    System.out.println("largest: " + max);
    System.out.println("even: " + oddsCounter);
    System.out.println("odd: " + evensCounter);
    System.out.println("average: " + average);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what youre looking for

```
 while(scan.hasNextInt())
        {

            getInt = scan.nextInt();
//            if(true)
//            {
                if (getInt%2==0)
                {
                    evensCounter++;
                    System.out.println("even: " + evensCounter);
                }
                else
                {
                    oddsCounter++;
                    System.out.println("odd: " + oddsCounter);
                }

                //getInt = scan.nextInt();

                if(getInt < min)
                {
                    min = getInt;
                }
                else if(getInt > max)
                {
                    max = getInt;
                }
//            }
//            else
//            {
//                notnull = false;
//            }

            sum += getInt;
            System.out.println("sum " +sum);
            count++;
            System.out.println("count " +count);
            average = (double)sum/(count);
            System.out.println("average " +average);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There were five mistakes in your program

1. You were printing incorrectly (  System.out.println("even: " + oddsCounter)).  Even should be printed as evencounter
2. You have to make the sum also a double or float, to get the average in decimal format.
3. You have to read the getINT before you do the odd even test.
4. Even/odd calculation was wrong. it should be getInt%2==0
5. You should not have the if/else while calculating min and max.  it should be two separate if's

Full working program below.

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework7APrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out
                .println("Enter a sequence of integers. Any non-integer to quit");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        int oddsCounter = 0;
        int evensCounter = 0;
        int getInt = 0;
        double average = 0;

```
    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {

        getInt = scan.nextInt();
        if (getInt % 2 == 0) {
            evensCounter++;
            // System.out.println("even: " + evensCounter);
        } else {
            oddsCounter++;
            // System.out.println("odd: " + oddsCounter);
        }

        if (getInt < min) 
        {
            min = getInt;
        }

        if (getInt > max)
        {
            max = getInt;
        }

        sum += getInt;
        // System.out.println("sum " +sum);
        count++;
        // System.out.println("count " +count);
        average = sum / (count);
        // System.out.println("average " +average);
    }
    System.out.println("*****************");
    System.out.println("smallest: " + min);
    System.out.println("largest: " + max);
    System.out.println("even: " + evensCounter);
    System.out.println("odd: " + oddsCounter);
    System.out.println("average: " + average);
    System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
    System.out.println("count: " + count);
}
```

}

Comment: Hello Joe, if I input
9
3
7
1
q

the largest number is somehow 7

Comment: Hey user... that is because the if else for min max calculation was wrong.  I modified the program.